# What can I do to collect usage statistics for a local web application deployed on Glassfish behind Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, glassfish, analytics

I have an application running in Glassfish v2.1 which does not have access to the outside world, so I cannot use Google Analytics or something else that has to phone home. It needs to be local to our server.

I want to be able to measure:

- page load times
- form submission
- page usage statistics (eg using page X, Y more often than Z)

Again this has to be local to my application server and can't 'phone home' to a central system.

Are there any options or add-ons for Glassfish which will help me collect usage statistics?

Are there any lightweight local analyitics packages that I could use?

Glassfish sits behind Apache, are there any tools that apache provides to help with this?

Comment: Other than the fact that Awstats doesn't provide page load times / form submission-statistics - I don't understand why you couldn't use it.  It uses Apache's logfiles as an input.

Comment: Edited. AWStats was a bad example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[javamelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) - it works inside the applications, you have to add at least one filter to the `web.xml`.

Comment: JavaMelody isn't perfect, but its damn good. Took like 15 minutes to set up and gives us enough data to know where to focus our efforts. Enjoy your bounty!